# Evaluating arithmetic sum using prime factorization

Tags: number-theory

Please help! I have no idea how to start this problem / what to do to evaluate this.

For m>0 , let f(m) = $\sum_{r=1}^{m} \frac{m}{gcd(m,r)}$ . Evaluate f(m) in terms of the prime factorization of m.

Comment: Hint: it's the sum of the orders of all elements in the cyclic group of order $m$.

Comment: I would do this one but if it's going to be closed it's not worth typesetting the answer.

Comment: @lhf I'm not exactly sure what that is.. We haven't discussed that in our number theory class and this is the only advanced math class I have had so far other than intro to advanced ( basic proofing ) .

Comment: @MarkoRiedel I would appreciate any help at all you could give.. This problem is worth a project grade for my class and I really need to do good on it.

Comment: @JonathanSeeman The answer is there. I'm not sure of the proceedings if your question gets closed. I will try to re-open if it does. I think this is a fair question and my answer leaves enough material for you to work on.

Comment: There is the possibility of an answer more suitable to the syllabus of an introductory number theory course should the question stay open.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel the question will stay open, the first answer you had was very nice, but most of what you had used had not been discussed with us so far. It did however give me a few ideas that may be helpful in me solving this. Any simpler answer would be very much appreciated from you!

Answer (score 0):

To start, you should verify that if the prime factorization of $m$ is equal to $p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_i^{\alpha_i}$, then $f(m) = f(p_1^{\alpha_1}) \times f(p_2^{\alpha_2})\times \dots \times f(p_i^{\alpha_i})$.  In other words, $f$ is what is termed a multiplicative function in number theory.  Use the Chinese remainder theorem for this.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have
$$f(n) = \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{n}{\gcd(n,r)}
= n \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{\gcd(n,r)}.$$

This is
$$n \sum_{d|n} 
\sum_{r=1, \atop \gcd(n,r)=d}^n \frac{1}{d}
= n \sum_{d|n} \frac{1}{d}
\sum_{r=1, \atop \gcd(n/d,r)=1}^{n/d} 1
\\ = n \sum_{d|n} \frac{1}{d} \phi(n/d)
= n \sum_{d|n} \frac{1}{n/d} \phi(d)
= \sum_{d|n} d\phi(d).$$

Now since $\sum_{d|n} \phi(d) = n$ we have
$$\zeta(s) \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{\phi(n)}{n^s} =
\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{n}{n^s}
\quad\text{and hence}\quad
\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{\phi(n)}{n^s} = \frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)}.$$

and
$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{\phi(n)}{n^{s-1}} 
= \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{n \phi(n)}{n^{s}} 
= \frac{\zeta(s-2)}{\zeta(s-1)}.$$

It follows that
$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{f(n)}{n^{s}} 
= \zeta(s) \frac{\zeta(s-2)}{\zeta(s-1)}.$$

This gives the Euler product
$$\prod_p \frac{1}{1-1/p^s} \frac{1}{1-1/p^{s-2}}
(1-1/p^{s-1}).$$

This has two contributions which emerge from the nonfractional term.

The first is
$$\frac{1}{1-z}\frac{1}{1-p^2z}
= \frac{p^2}{p^2-1}\frac{1}{1-p^2z}
+ \frac{1}{1-p^2}\frac{1}{1-z}.$$

This gives for the coefficient on $p^v$ the contribution
$$\frac{p^2}{p^2-1} p^{2v} + \frac{1}{1-p^2}.$$

The second is
$$\frac{p^3}{p^2-1}\frac{z}{1-p^2z}
+ \frac{p}{1-p^2}\frac{z}{1-z}.$$

This gives for the coefficient on $p^v$ the contribution
$$\frac{p^3}{p^2-1} p^{2v-2} + \frac{p}{1-p^2}.$$

Therefore we finally have $f(1)=1$ and
$$f(p^v) =
\frac{p^2}{p^2-1} p^{2v} + \frac{1}{1-p^2}
- \frac{p^3}{p^2-1} p^{2v-2} - \frac{p}{1-p^2}.$$

This simplifies to
$$\frac{(p-1)p^{1+2v} + p-1}{p^2-1}
= \frac{p^{1+2v} + 1}{p+1}.$$