# Prove summations are equal

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, induction

Prove that:

$$\sum_{r=1}^{p^n} \frac{p^n}{gcd(p^n,r)} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k  p^{2n-k} = p^{2n} - p^ {2n-1} + p^{2n-2} - ... + p^{2n-2n}$$

I'm not exactly sure how to do this unless I can say:

*Assume*  $\sum_{r=1}^{p^n} \frac{p^n}{gcd(p^n,r)}$ = $\sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k  p^{2n-k}$

and show by induction that the sums equal each other and show the inductive step that you can take the expanded sum part with $n+1$ and get to $\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} (-1)^k  p^{2(n+1)-k}$

However, I'm not even sure that I am allowed to do this.. Any suggestion in how to prove this? I'm not looking for a whole proof just a push in the direction of how to solve this.

Comment: This was discussed at the following [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1230686), which in fact points to two threads on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $gcd(p^n,r)$ for $r=\overline{1,p^n}$ must be of the form $p^k$ with $k\in\overline{0,n}$, and for each $k$ there is exactly $\phi(p^{n-k})$ numbers with that property in $\overline{1,p^n}$ so:
$$\sum_{r=1}^{p^n} \frac{p^n}{gcd(p^n,r)} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{p^n}{p^k}\phi(p^{n-k}) = 1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{p^n}{p^k}p^{n-k}(1-\frac{1}{p}) = 1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} p^{2(n-k)}(1-\frac{1}{p}) = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k  p^{2n-k} \square$$
For the last equality:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} p^{2(n-k)}(1-\frac{1}{p}) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (p^{2(n-k)}-p^{2(n-k)-1})= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ((-1)^{2(n-k)}p^{2(n-k)}+(-1)^{2(n-k)-1}p^{2(n-k)-1}) = \sum_{i=0}^{2n-1} (-1)^i p^{2n-i}$$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the " $r=1,n$ with the line over it? I think this was exactly what I needed though!

Comment: I think that $\overline{a, b}$ means the integers from $a$ through $b$. If this is so, then I think the first use should be $\overline{1, p^n}$, not $\overline{1, n}$.

Comment: Okay thats kinda what I was thinking it was... Also, how exactly do you get $\sum_{k=1}^{n} p^{2(n-k)}(1-\frac{1}{p}) = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k  p^{2n-k}$ And what is the square at the end?

Comment: @martycohen yes that's what it means, and thanks for pointing out the mistake

Comment: @JonathanSeeman $\overline{a,b}$ means the integer numbers from $a$ to $b$ inclusive, and the last equality was not true for $k=1$ to $n$ it must be from $k=0$ was a mistake fixed now.

Comment: @JonathanSeeman for the meaning of the square look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.

Comment: @xndrme Ah okay I see. The only problem I still have is how to manipulate the last equality still to give the final result. Could you maybe show the work that it takes to get there? I have no idea how you got there.

Comment: @JonathanSeeman I've added an explanation, hope it helps, also thanks to this effort I spotted another error in the sums, check the answer again please, sorry for the mistakes but my first answer was a kind of outline ;), I hope no mistakes were left now.

Comment: @xndrme Thank you so much for this! It helps a whole ton! :) , but where did the 1+ on the beginning come from if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @JonathanSeeman Of course I don't mind! The $+1$ comes from the case when $k=n$ in that case the term in the sum becomes $\frac{p^n}{p^n}\phi(p^0)$ and as convention you can take $\phi(1)=1$, in fact in that case you are counting the numbers $r$ with $gcd(r,p^n)=p^n$ which can only be one, namely $p^n$, and there you have the $+1$ in the sum, hope it helps.

Comment: @xndrme Yeah I actually just realized that a few minutes after posting my comment haha. Very last question then I think I understand the entire thing completely, how exactly are we able to go from $\sum_{r=1}^{p^n} \frac{p^n}{gcd(p^n,r)} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{p^n}{p^k}\phi(p^{n-k})$ .

Comment: @JonathanSeeman the idea is to look at the problem from a different angle, the first sums tells you: "Add all the terms of the form $\frac{p^n}{gcd(p^n,r)}$" while the second sum says this "The previous sum is the same that adding all the numbers grouped by their $gcd$ with $p^n$" and as the $gcd$ must be of the form $p^k$ then you should be able to sum the numbers grouped by $p^0,p^1,p^2\dots,p^n$ as their $gcd$s and thats exactly what it does. Sometimes mathematics is about creativity, not all is formulas and numbers. I hope my explanation helps you to grasp the idea.

Comment: @xndrme You are a life saver haha. Thank you so much for all the help you've given me on this! You've made it so very clear with all of your explanations!